firefox and firefox esr at the same time
I have firefox from ppa on kubuntu 22.04. Now I want to install firefox esr additionally. Without mixing up with the already installed normal firefox. There is a  thread here already but it doesn´t say how to do it....;)
edit: snap is not an option because the plugin I want to use on it only works with firefox-esr installed via apt

I use the mozillateam ppa which provides both packages, firefox and firefox-esr.
I just tested and  installed firefox-esr with sudo apt install firefox-esr.
This will not mix up with your previous firefox-installation. The profiles for firefox-esr are stored in a seperate folder:

firefox uses  ~/.mozilla/firefox
firefox-esr uses ~/.mozilla/firefox-esr


works, that simple, great, thx.

Use the Snap firefox package for your second install.
Your Firefox profile will be stored in a different location when using the Snap package. Each Firefox will have different profiles that cannot see each other, preventing "mixing up".

@mook765 big edit to answer the question more clearly.

snap is not an option in this special case

Please edit your question to add constraints.
